# What are the effects of regularly passively smoking marijuana?

Tags: side-effects, smoking, lungs, marijuana

Does the regular passive smoking of marijuana have specific effects in addition to those of passive cigarette smoking?

Comment: Welcome!  Not upvoted.  Please don't ask two questions in one post.  Please [edit] and fix.

Comment: I edited your question to clarify. If my edits altered the intent of your question, feel free to undo them.

Comment: Thanks Gregory.

unforgettableid 7, In my opinion, there is one question in my question, no more.